# MySQL Slow log file - showing every query log

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up the slow log file in mysql.

I want all the queries that took more than 20 seconds to be logged.

**However, I see every query logged in the slow log file. Can anybody explain this?**

Mysql version - 5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

The settings are as follows

slow_query_log - ON
 long_query_time - 20
show global variables like 'log_queries%' ---> OFF

Any ideas on this would be of great help

Thanks 
Rathi

Comment: What OS you are running?

Comment: maybe all your queries are slow?

Comment: The OS is ubuntu0.14.04.1. I have checked and not all my queries are slow

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this...
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time = 20
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1
```

The last line tells MySQL to log *any* queries that do not use indexes regardless of the setting in the first line. If your tables are not using indexes then you might wanna change last line to 0.